# Advice for high availability

Tags: windows, active-directory, high-availability

Talking about high availability im in search of advice for my particular situation. We have configured a blade center from ibm our active directory server using vmware (windows server 2008 r2), and works pretty well but what worries me is the availability of our services. So I searched for high availability solution, I found failover cluster in windows server features, but I also found aditional domain controllers along with secondary DNS service. My question is what is the difference between adding a domain controller and a failover? And what is your advice for my virtualized situation? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Note: Extended support for Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 ends on 1/14/2020. You may want to consider upgrading in 2019.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You should have at least two Domain Controllers.
2. You can create a VMware HA (high availability) cluster if you have the resources and licenses. This would protect you against a ESXi host failure.
3. In a VMware HA cluster you should place your Domain Controllers on different cluster nodes.

Comment: Thank you for answer. So, can i make a vmware cluster even with different windows server version? Should I forget the idea of failover cluster with windows server features? Making now a dns primary and secondary, 2 domain controllers in different servers is a good option for minor problems?

Comment: What do you mean? You're running ESXi on your physical server, right?

Comment: Yes. Its workstation though. I mean, can i use vmware cluster with 2008 and 2012 windows servers? Oh, 2008 server was setup a year ago, 2012 was installed yesterday.

Comment: Don't do this. Don't put production workloads on a desktop virtualization product. VMware Workstation is not intended for production workloads. Use a Type 1 bare metal hypervisor like ESXI or Hyper-V for production workloads.

Comment: Its installed on ibm bladecenter, not sure what version of vmware is. But is server aimed. I just know esxi 6.5 (free, on what i did some test, not installed on blade btw). Thank you.

Comment: Should i create a cluster with vmware or create another domain controller along with a secondary dns? Thanks!